# JQuery $.ajax() function not running POST request accurately

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following html

```
<select id="options" title="prd_name1" name="options" onblur="getpricefromselect(this);" onchange="getpricefromselect(this);"></select>
```

and an

```
<input type="text" id="prd_price" title="prd_price1" name="prd_price">
```

I have a dynamically updated the `<select></select>` with a few products and their respective ids from the system database. I have written a JQuery/Javascript function which is suppose to send that product id from the select menu to a php page using $.ajax() and getting its respective price from database and populating the `<input>` with that price.

My jQuery is as follows:

```
function getpricefromselect(x){

    var value=$(x).val();
    var title=$(x).attr('title');

    if(title.length == 9){
        var len=Number((title).substr(-1,1));    

        if(value.length>0){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'getpricefromselect.php',
                data:{productid: value},
                success:function(data){
                    $("[title=prd_price"+len+"]").val(data).show();
                }
            })
        }
    }
};
```

And the php in the "getpricefromselect.php" is as follows:

```
$productid="";
$Price="";
$productid=$_POST["productid"];
$selectProduct="SELECT InventoryProductPrice FROM InventoryProductsList WHERE InventoryProductID = '{$productid}';";
$selectProduct_query = mysqli_query($connection, $selectProduct);
if(!$selectProduct_query){
    die ("Database query for selecting Product Price failed.");
}
while ($selectProduct_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectProduct_query)){
    $Price= $selectProduct_array["InventoryProductPrice"];
}
echo $Price;
```

The issue is that the jQuery $.ajax() populates the `<input>` with a blank item when I echo $Price from php file but if I echo $productid it populates the `<input>` with the accurate productid. My Product ID is unique to every product and when I call the same php function on the same page as javascript it returns the accurate price. Can anyone tell me why is $.ajax() getting back a blank item if $Price is echoed from php and it does not give a blank item if $productid is echoed from php.

If I add the actual product id manually to the php file the $Price echoed by php is accurate. If it is sent through POST from $.ajax() it seems to not being run accurately by php.

Comment: So console.log(data); gives exactly what in your `success` callback? And what does the network console show that the server is returning?

Comment: yes thats true. console.log and success show same, the issue is with $,ajax not either properly sending POST request or perhaps php page not running POST accurately.

Comment: Is your `InventoryProductID` an `INT` field? If so try removing the single quotes `'` from here `'{$productid}'`. Change it to this `{$productid}`.

Comment: The network console under developer tools will be able to tell you exactly that - it'll show what the client is sending to the server (look at the bottom of the request pane) and what the server is returning (look at the preview/response). This should tell you where you should start looking - either the value isn't correct when you're sending it, or wrong when you're getting it back.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you used the developer console to see what answers the query brings, or what problem with the ajax request.

On the other hand, you can try like this

```
$(function(){
    $("#options").change(function()){
        getpricefromselect($(this).val());
    });
})


function getpricefromselect(x){

    var obj = {
        productid:x
    }

    $.post('getpricefromselect.php',obj)
    .done(function(resp){
        if(resp){
            $("#prd_price").val(resp)
        }
    })
    .fail(function(err){

    })

};
```

Comment: No errors in the console and if I use console.log it places blank item in Console when $Price is echoed and the accurate $productid if it is echoed from php file.

Comment: So that the while loop ??? Three more than one result in the query ???? or is it just one?